# Captcha image is not showing at admin login

Tags: admin, magento-1, captcha

This has just started happening, I can't login to the **backend** as it won't let me past the **Catchpa** which is showing as a broken image. How can I get in?

Comment: magento version?

Comment: Update the sceenshot as well with Magento version. Captcha should only appears when you type wrong passwords. For the first, it will not show captcha. Also check the permission of pub/media/captcha/ directory. Set correct permissions to that folder and test again.

Comment: Version 1.x (not sure of the x number). The catchpa shows up after I've input the correct password for a second login.  I have access to the ftp files but I don't know how to use the database (I didnt develop it, I just own it) so not sure how to access the permissions